# Seleccionar el menor inmediato SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito hacer una consulta en ***mysql*** donde tengo dos tablas venta y compra
estas tienen el campo fecha y quiero sacar 
**c.fechacompra < v.fechaventa**
El problema es que tengo muchas **fechacompra** menor que la **fechaventa** y la consulta saca el menor de todos y no el menor inmediato, es decir la fecha mas reciente de entre las anteriores a **fechaventa**.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir tu consulta entera para ver dónde puede estar la problemática? Un saludo y bienvenido!

Comment: Hola, aqui publique la informacion mas completa:

http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/16164/consulta-sql-para-sacar-el-precio-de-compra-antes-de-la-venta

Comment: Hola aqui puse la informacion completa : http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/16164/consulta-sql-para-sacar-el-precio-de-compra-antes-de-la-venta

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando la función [`MAX`](http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_func_max.asp) de SQL puedes realizar lo que necesitas.

Entiendo por tu pregunta que tienes 2 tablas y a partir de esas sólo necesitas la fecha de compra más cercana a la primera fecha de venta (no tiene mucho sentido, creo que deberáis actualizar tu pregunta) y debes juntar con una `join` con los productos. Para hacer eso:

```
select Max(c.fechacompra) as UltimaCompra
from compras c
join ventas v on c.ProductoID = v.ProductoID
where c.fechacompra < v.fechaventa
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que he entendido de tu pregunta prueba añadiendo un `ORDER BY (CAMPO) (ASC/DESC)`, con esto puedes elegir el orden para que te coja el menor, pero si además lo que quieres es que el resultado de la consulta de devuelva 1 exclusivo registro puedes añadir `FETCH FOR 1 ROW ONLY`.