# Consulta SQL para sacar el precio de compra antes de la venta

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Tengo una base de datos (adjunto BD [abrir BD para importar](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwKQe42j2yjFUmJYOEx4aUUwMzg/view?usp=sharing)), en donde quiero sacar un reporte en la cual me saque el listado de venta de cada producto en facturas, mostrando cuanto lo vendí y cuanto me costó.
El problema es que la consulta que saco:

---

```
SELECT p.id, p.descripcion, (vp.valor * vp.cantidad) as valor_total, fv.id ,fv.fechaventa, fc.id as fc_id ,fc.fecha_compra, (pc.precio_compra * vp.cantidad)

FROM venta_producto vp

inner join factura_venta fv on fv.id = vp.id_venta

inner join producto p on p.id = vp.id_producto

left join producto_compra pc on pc.id_producto = p.id

left join factura_compra fc on fc.id = pc.id_compra and fc.fecha_compra < fv.fechaventa 

group by fv.id, p.id

ORDER BY p.id, fv.id ASC
```

---

y en **fc.fecha_compra < fv.fechaventa**  El problema es que tengo muchas fecha_compra menor que la fechaventa y la consulta saca el menor de todos y no el menor inmediato (la fecha mas reciente de entre las anteriores a fechaventa)
Es decir pone como precio compra la primera de toda la base de datos.

> la consulta, la quiero hacer para comparar en cuanto se vendio y cuanto
>   me costo (puede que ya haya comprado de nuevo ese producto 
>   despues de la venta cuando quiera generar el reporte, entonces debe de sacar no la ultima compra, si no
>   la ultima compra antes de vender)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisalo y me confirmas como te va con este reporte... seria bueno crear vistas que ayudan a muchos de los procesos....

```
SELECT 
    P.id, P.descripcion, 
    V2.fechaventa, V2.fv_id, V2.id_producto, V2.valor_venta, 
    C2.id as fc_id, C2.fecha_compra, IFNULL(C2.precio_compra * V2.cantidad, 0) AS valor_compra
FROM (
    SELECT 
        MAX(C1.fecha_compra) AS fecha_compra, 
        V1.fechaventa, V1.fv_id, V1.id_producto, SUM(V1.cantidad) AS cantidad, SUM(V1.valor_total) AS valor_venta
    FROM (
        SELECT FV.fechaventa, FV.id AS fv_id, VP.id_producto, VP.cantidad, (VP.valor * VP.cantidad) AS valor_total
        FROM venta_producto AS VP
            INNER JOIN factura_venta AS FV 
                ON FV.id = VP.id_venta
        ) AS V1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT FC.fecha_compra, PC.id_producto
            FROM producto_compra AS PC
                INNER JOIN factura_compra AS FC
                    ON PC.id_compra = FC.id
        ) AS C1
        ON C1.id_producto = V1.id_producto
        AND C1.fecha_compra < V1.fechaventa
    GROUP BY V1.fechaventa, V1.fv_id, V1.id_producto
) AS V2
    INNER JOIN producto AS P 
        ON P.id = V2.id_producto
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT Fc.id, FC.fecha_compra, PC.id_producto, AVG(PC.precio_compra) AS precio_compra
        FROM producto_compra AS PC
            INNER JOIN factura_compra AS FC
                ON PC.id_compra = FC.id
        GROUP BY Fc.id, FC.fecha_compra, PC.id_producto
    ) AS C2
        ON C2.id_producto = V2.id_producto
        AND C2.fecha_compra = V2.fecha_compra
ORDER BY P.id, P.descripcion, V2.fechaventa, V2.fv_id, V2.id_producto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Qué tal?

Si entendí bien tu duda, este código lo resuelve; la primer consulta crea un tabla temporal que nos indica cuales compras aplican como realizadas antes de la fecha de venta y las abandera. La segunda, que es la definitiva, filtra los registros con la bandera y solo devuelve la fecha máxima de compra antes de la fecha de venta.

```
SELECT
p.id as [Pid]
,p.descripcion as [descripcion]
,(vp.valor * vp.cantidad) as [valor_total]
,fv.id as [FVid]
,fv.fechaventa as [fechaventa]
,fc.id as [FCid]
,fc.fecha_compra as [fechacompra]
,(pc.precio_compra * vp.cantidad) as [totalcantidad]
,CASE
    WHEN fc.fecha_compra < fv.fechaventa THEN 1
    ELSE 0
 END AS [ValidaFechaCompra]
 into #tablaTMP1
FROM venta_producto vp
inner join factura_venta fv on fv.id = vp.id_venta
inner join producto p on p.id = vp.id_producto
left join producto_compra pc on pc.id_producto = p.id
left join factura_compra fc on fc.id = pc.id_compra
group by fv.id, p.id

select
 #tablaTMP1.[Pid]
 , max(#tablaTMP1.[fechacompra])
 ,tmp2.valor_total
 ,tmp2.totalcantidad
 from #tablaTMP1 inner join (select [Pid],[fechacompra], [valor_total], [totalcantidad] from #tablaTMP1) as tmp2
    on #tablaTMP1.Pid = tmp2.Pid and max(#tablaTMP1.[fechacompra]) = tmp2.fechacompra
where #tablaTMP1.ValidaFechaCompra = 1
```

Comment: Hola ToCarbajal, al momento de ejecutar el codigo me genera error de sintaxsis.
Que deberia modificar? 

Gracias por su respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

¿Intentaste solo agregar un `Having`?

El `Having` es como un `Where` para datos agregados, sería algo cómo:

```
SELECT 
    p.id, p.descripcion, (vp.valor * vp.cantidad) as valor_total ...
.....
Where 
    fc.fecha_compra < fv.fechaventa
ORDER BY p.id, fv.id ASC
HAVING MAX(fc.fecha_compra)
```

Esto debería servirte.